# Path Query in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

This question is based on my earlier  [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22372991/query-using-neo4j-embedded-in-java)  on neo4j

I am trying to find out the names of the person living in city 'X'. I am using 2 nodes: Person and City for this purpose and a relationship exists [LIVES_IN]. I have created 4 nodes and 2 relationships as such:

```
CREATE (m:Person { name : 'sa', paswrd : 'abc' });
CREATE (n:Person { name : 'ti', paswrd : 'abc' });
CREATE (o:City { name : 'pune' });
CREATE (p:City { name : 'mumbai' });
CREATE (m)-[:LIVES_IN]->(o);
CREATE (n)-[:LIVES_IN]->(o);
```

Now, to get the persons who are living in 'pune' i try to write this query:

```
MATCH (x:City)<-[:LIVES_IN]-(y:Person) where x.name='pune' RETURN y.name;
```

But it returns:

```
==> +--------+
==> | y.name |
==> +--------+
==> +--------+
==> 0 row
==> 47 ms
```

Can you please advise me how to do it, then? For your kind information, I am presently using Neo4j2.0.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works for me. Are you sure you're running the same code you posted?

http://console.neo4j.org/r/p3cqal

Comment: Alright, then I'll remove the java tag in your question.

Comment: @Wes Freeman: How can you get the result. in my case I am still getting y.name contains 0 rows.

Comment: I made a mistake in where. It should be WHERE. Thank You Wes Freeman and tstorms for your kind support.