# Neo4j query in Java application :No result is displaying[Still fail to solve it]

Tags: java, swing, nosql, neo4j, cypher

**Updated Question**

This question is based on my earlier [post1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22372991/query-using-neo4j-embedded-in-java)  and [post2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22382712/path-query-in-neo4j) on neo4j.

I am trying to find out the persons lives in a city.
I am using 2 nodes: person and city and the relationship between these two is (person)-[:LIVES_IN]->(city).

After following the suggestions given by mentors on my previous posts, I did some modification .

But it displays only the current person name is added for that city.

My codes are following:(Here remains 3 text boxes, 2 buttons and 1 text area)

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.GraphDatabaseService;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.Node;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.RelationshipType;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.Transaction;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory;
import org.neo4j.helpers.collection.IteratorUtil;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import org.neo4j.cypher.javacompat.ExecutionEngine;
import org.neo4j.cypher.javacompat.ExecutionResult;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.Label;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.schema.IndexDefinition;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.schema.Schema;

enum labels implements Label {
    Person,
    City
}
public class registrationFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {


    public static final String DB_PATH = "D://data";
    public static GraphDatabaseService graphDb = null;
    Node person;
    Node password;
    Node city;
    String nodeResulta;
    String rows = "";
    Schema schema = null;
    boolean e = false;    

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
       //Schema index on Person and person node creation
        try (Transaction tx = graphDb.beginTx()) {
            schema = graphDb.schema();

            for (IndexDefinition id : graphDb.schema().getIndexes()) {
                e = true;
            }
            if (!e)
                schema.indexFor(labels.Person).on("name").create();                    
            tx.success();
        }
        try (Transaction tx = graphDb.beginTx();) {
            person = graphDb.createNode(labels.Person);
            person.setProperty("name", jTextField1.getText());
            person.setProperty("password", jPasswordField1.getPassword());
            graphDb.index().forNodes("name").add(person, "name", jTextField1.getText());            

            tx.success();
        }
//Schema index on City and city node creation and relationship establishment
        try (Transaction tx = graphDb.beginTx()) {
            schema = graphDb.schema();

            for (IndexDefinition id : graphDb.schema().getIndexes()) {
                e = true;
            }
            if (!e)
                schema.indexFor(labels.City).on("city_name").create();
            tx.success();
        }
        try (Transaction tx = graphDb.beginTx();) {
            city = graphDb.createNode(labels.City);
            city.setProperty("city_name", jTextField2.getText());        
            graphDb.index().forNodes("city_name").add(city, "city_name", jTextField2.getText());            

            person.createRelationshipTo(city, RelTypes.LIVES_IN);               

            tx.success();
        }

    }                                        
    private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        ExecutionEngine engine = new ExecutionEngine(graphDb);
        ExecutionResult result;
        String temp=jTextField2.getText();
        Map<String,Object> params=new HashMap<>();

        try (Transaction ignored = graphDb.beginTx()) {

            params.put("c_name",temp);
            // **the query advised by Luanne for finding person living in same city**
            result=engine.execute("MATCH (city:City {city_name:{c_name}})<-[:LIVES_IN]-(person) RETURN person",params);
            System.out.println(result);
            Iterator<Node> n_column = result.columnAs("person");

            for (Node node : IteratorUtil.asIterable(n_column)) {

                System.out.println("hiii");
                nodeResulta = node + ": " + node.getProperty("name")  + '\n';
            }
            // END SNIPPET: items
        }

        jTextArea1.setText(nodeResulta);

    }    
    public static enum RelTypes implements RelationshipType {

        LIVES_IN,
        FRIEND,
        CUISINE,
        LIKES,
        IN
    } 

}
```

I have tried to debug the code and found that result is returning only the current person who is added for that city not the list of persons.

What is the reason behind such behavior?
Can any mentor advise me in this regard?
Shall I change my neo4j version because I am following everything as Luanne and Miheal Hunger has asked.

Thank You
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your query expects `x` to have the label `:city` and `y` to have the label `:person`. Where in your code do you give these nodes those labels? If you don't assign the labels then the query cannot find anything with those labels. Also, the indices you create are legacy indices. You probably want label indices per http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/tutorials-java-embedded-new-index.html

Comment: @jjaderberg: My idea is labels are declaring in neo4j on the fly.city and person are holding the label x and y on the fly. I created indices on name property of person and city_name property of city using graphDb.index().forNodes("city_name").add(city, "city_name", jTextField2.getText()); and graphDb.index().forNodes("name").add(person, "name", jTextField1.getText()); As I commented for Michael Hunger's post, All the queries are executed normally in neo4j browser but when I am embedding them in java then the it returns nothing

Comment: @jjaderberg: I updated my code as adding label indices. But the result appears same.

Answer (score 3):

Try to stick to Cypher that makes it much easier.

Do the [online tutorial](http://neo4j.org/learn/online_course) to get you up to speed. Also use the [Cypher Reference Card](http://neo4j.org/resources/cypher).

Prototype your model in the Neo4j browser until **all** your create and query statements work.

Then use those cypher statements with parameter placeholders, e.g. `{name}` to be fed from your program via `executionEngine.execute(query,params)`.

Right now you have too many moving parts and explaining one part won't help you to learn the concepts.

Comment: Thank You, mentor. In my "post1", you advised me this"executionEngine.execute(query,params)."All the queries are running successfully in neo4j browser(Nodes and relationships are created as well as the query is also executed). But when I am embedding the query in java in this way "MATCH (x:city)<-[:LIVES_IN]-(y:person) where x.name='"+jTextField2.getText()+"' RETURN y", it fails to work. I have already done indexing on city_name property by :graphDb.index().forNodes("city_name").add(city, "city_name", jTextField2.getText()); I think that I made something wrong in java portion.

Comment: You added a legacy index but you want a schema index. That one is added with "CREATE INDEX ON :City(city)". Also you need to add the `:City` label to the node when you create it. Note that it is capitalized camel case.

Comment: I updated my code as you advised. I added labels and generate schema index but it is displaying only the current person who is added at the city. I updated my code above. I am earnestly looking for your help, mentor.

Comment: Can you either zip your database and share it or execute the dump command and share the contents (http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/shell-commands.html#_dumping_the_database_or_a_cypher_result_to_cypher_statements).